# Remove \u characters, but preserve non-latin letters

Tags: python

I have a file that includes random unicode characters, for example `\u204c` that I'd like to remove, but it also has non-latin characters. So an example text could be `"dzień do\u204cbry miły książę"` and I'd like the text to be left with `"dzień dobry miły książę"`. An approach with `s.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('utf-8')` removes all but latin characters leaving me with `"dzie dobry miy ksi"`. Is there a method to remove only `\u` characters?

Comment: Python's standard `unicodedata` module has a `category()` function that will classify Unicode characters - you'd just need to decide which categories contain the characters you want to keep.  `"Ll"`, `"Lu"`, and `"Zs"` should get you started.

Comment: I didn't know of that function, it was useful in my case, thanks!